# c++ expression must be a modifiable lvalue Classes

Tags: c++, class

I was doing the foundation of a class program and I was trying to modify the value of an object of the class:
In the main.cc:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "ComputeInt.h" 
main() 
{  ComputeInt computation; 
   computation.real() = 5; 
   computation.operator=(Factorial(computation)); 
}
```

In the .h:

```
#include <iostream> 
#ifndef ComputeInt_H 
#define ComputeInt_H 
class ComputeInt
{  public: 
     int real();
}; 
ComputeInt Factorial(const ComputeInt& computation); 
#endif
```

In the .cc:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "ComputeInt.h" 
ComputeInt Factorial(const ComputeInt& computation) 
{  ComputeInt result = computation.real() +1;
   return result; 
}
```

I get an error that says expression must be a modifiable lvalue, and if I try to use make I get

```
conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘ComputeInt’ requested
```

I don´t know why it doesn´t work, computation.real is a int and so it should be able to use +1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the code, but the page said that it was wrongly written, I will try here:

Comment: .cc
#include <iostream>
#include "ComputeInt.h"
main() {
  ComputeInt computation; 
  computation.real() = 5;
  computation.operator=(Factorial(computation)); 
}
.h
#include <iostream>
#ifndef ComputeInt_H
#define ComputeInt_H
class ComputeInt{
public:
int real();
};
ComputeInt Factorial(const ComputeInt& computation);
#endif
main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "ComputeInt.h"
ComputeInt Factorial(const ComputeInt& computation) {
  ComputeInt result = computation.real() +1;
  return result;
}

Comment: Just copy/paste whatever code you want in your question and don't worry about formatting. We will reformat it for you since it is your first time. But don't post images of code. Note i said in the question not in the comment section.

Comment: I cannot, I get Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Well, did you add 4 spaces before each line? Or you can add triple backticks ``` before and after each code block.

Comment: What is `computation.real() = 5;` supposed to do? That assignment makes no sense.

Comment: [The stack overflow editing/formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

Method real() returns integer by value so if you do:

```
computation.real() = 5;
```

you try to assign value "5" to another value. It is not possible, similarly like you are not allowed to do:

```
3 = 5;
```

---

```
conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘ComputeInt’ requested
```

There is no known conversion from int you created by `real()+1` to ComputeInt (you don't have constructor and/or operator=)

Comment: Note that it is not possible only for fundamental types. For example, you can do `std::list<int> l; l.begin() = l.end();`, although this assignment doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

In your current program `real` is a **member function** of the class `ComputeInt` and not a **data member**. So you can solve this issue as shown below:

**.h**

```
#ifndef ComputeInt_H 
#define ComputeInt_H
class ComputeInt
{  public: 
     int real;//removed () here. This means real is a data member now
};
ComputeInt Factorial(const ComputeInt& computation);
#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "ComputeInt.h" 
ComputeInt Factorial(const ComputeInt& computation) 
{  ComputeInt result ; //create object of type ComputeInt
   result.real= computation.real +1; //note result.real at the left hand side
   return result; 
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ComputeInt.h" 
#include<iostream>
int main() 
{  ComputeInt computation; 
   computation.real = 5; 
   
   ComputeInt computation2;
   computation2.real = 10;
   
   computation.operator=(Factorial(computation2)); 
   std::cout<<computation.real;//this prints 11
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/uV-h2ui3m).

Comment: @DanielMarhuenda Did you take a look at my answer. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I guess `int real{0};` was the intended behavior. Though they got the most vexing parse instead.

Comment: @JVApen Yeah that is a possibility. Maybe OP wasn't aware of C++'s most vexing parse.

Answer (score 1):

`int real()` is defined as a class method (function) that returns an int, not an int itself.

If you want to make it an int, make it `int real` without the `()`.